# Get values from modal JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am working on a map application in JavaFX. The idea is that the user should be able to update details of areas on the map. The map is a static image with invisible panes layered over it. I have a button in a form which will open a view of the map as a modal with relevant areas highlighted. When I select an area, the ID of that area is stored in a different class to be accessed and the modal closes, but what I would really like is to return the value to the controller of the form and trigger an event to change a label on the form.

Method call to display the map (contained within the controller of the form):

```
@FXML
private void selectArea()
{
    Main.viewLoader.displayRootSelection();
}
```

My view loader:

```
public void displayRootSelection(){
    Stage window = new Stage();
    currentWindow = window;
    Main.setRootInSelection(true);
    try {
        BorderPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../views/root/Root.fxml"));
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle("WIT Map");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600);
        Main.setScene(scene);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the event handler on the panels on the map:

```
@FXML
private void panelClicked(Event e)
{
    if (Main.isRootInSelection()){
        String tempId = AreaManagement.findArea((Node)e.getSource());
        AreaManagement.setTempAreaId(tempId);
        viewLoader.getCurrentWindow().close();
    }
    System.out.println(AreaManagement.findArea((Node) e.getSource()));
}
```

So what I am trying to do is get the tempId from the event handler in the controller for the map to the controller of the form and also trigger an event in the form. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your issue, correct me if I am wrong:

You open a modal window, using [`window.showAndWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--), then after closing the window you need to get the selected result from that modal window.

Under the assumption that `AreaManagement` is available within your `displayRootSelection()` Method, following solution should solve your problem.

Documentation for `window.showAndWait()`:

> Shows this stage and waits for it to be hidden (closed) before returning to the caller.

You can call any further handling right after that method call and safely assume that the modal window is closed. See:

```
public void displayRootSelection(Consumer<String> callback){//EDIT, usage see below
    Stage window = new Stage();
    currentWindow = window;
    Main.setRootInSelection(true);
    try {
        BorderPane root = ...;
        /*...*/
        window.showAndWait();
        // When the code reaches this position, your modal window is closed
        String tempId = AreaManagement.getTempAreaId();
        // You can call just about anything here
        callback.accept(tempId);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** get that method call back to the controller:

In the controller:

```
@FXML
private void selectArea()
{
    Main.viewLoader.displayRootSelection((selectedId) -> {
        // Do something with the ID..
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can create an anonymous class instead of using a lambda here.

Comment: This is almost what I need, except that I still can't quite figure how to trigger an event on my controller since I can't use static members or methods inside a controller. What I really need to do is call a static method on my controller from inside the ViewLoader that will change a static label injected from the FXML

Comment: Ah, I see. See my edited answer, that should get you what you need. If you insist on using a different approach, someone else will have to barge in - that is the simplest way I can think of.